# Touch screen enabled responsive banner slider

Tags: magento, slider, extension-methods, banner

which is the good extension for touch screen friendly responsive banner slider for magento? If it is not available free of cost then how to develop it?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmiM4oWGrLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution as jssor slider.Check http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/jssor-layered-slider.html.It works great.Good extension.Its a free extension.

Answer (score 0):

Paid responsive banner slider magento extension

```
Kindly check this one : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/slider-revolution-responsive-extension.html
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but this is not a touch friendly banner slider.